# iPad App Hangs on enumeratePreferredFocusEnvironments When Using Bluetooth Keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, keyboard, lag

App is mostly written in Swift with some Objective-C code. Recently I discovered that connecting a Bluetooth keyboard to the iPad causes some severe 2+ second hangs in this app.

Using Time Profiler has exposed the functions that are causing the hang (backtrace below), but my question is how can I stop this from happening? The CPU usage also spikes to 100%.

These hangs only happen when the Bluetooth keyboard is connected to the iPad. If I turn off Bluetooth on the iPad it goes back to running smoothly.

It seems to hang when I try and make touches that effect UI on the screen, but it isn't always the same actions that trigger the hang.

I tried to override these methods/variables around UIKit.UIFocus but it hasn't made any difference:

1. updateFocusIfNeeded - never hit despite being in the backtrace
2. shouldUpdateFocus - never hit
3. enumeratePreferredFocusEnvironments - returned empty array and is hit, but it still loops and hangs app

iPad is on iOS 16.3

[image: Backtrace. Can see most of time is in enumeratePreferredFocusEnvironments loop]

Comment: ran into this as well, any insight would be great

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the hangs by adding a tiny, clear UITextField on the UIViewController that was hanging.

It appears that the UIKit focusEnvironment code was looping through all the views looking for something to focus on for the keyboard, but because there wasn't anything to type inside available it searched long enough to hang the app. Now that I added the UITextField, it finds that to focus on and stops the looping.